# Gini Coefficient parallel/streaming implementation with unsorted input

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, gini

Is there a streaming implementation to compute the Gini Coefficient (not to be confused with the Gini Impurity used in decision trees induction) of an unsorted input?

Currently, I am aware of two implementation for the Gini Coefficient:

- One requires a sorted input and basically computes the Area Under the Lorenz Curve first and the ratio later
- Another requires an all pairs comparison of all the inputs (whether the input is sorted or not)

Is there a way to avoid sorting the input and also an n^2 all pairs comparison?

Comment: So looking for order n?

Comment: yes. An approximate algorithm would do it as well. Imagine doing this for 7B people without precomputation

Comment: At first glance I think that would be hard to do without nlogn, ie sorting. It seems like you need to know where each new person's income is in relation to the existing ones?

Comment: I think you are right. Now I am wondering whether I an AggregationFunction or a WindowFunction would be best for it

Comment: Actually, I believe that since I'm returning a single value for a group/partition (and not one new value for each row) an aggregation function would just do that for me

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65373894/how-do-i-enforce-ordering-order-by-in-a-custom-presto-aggregation-function